# How to click the form commit button in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

With Rails, rspec and capybara, I'm trying to test your typical ERB generated form:

```
<form action="/pages/1" id="edit_page_1" method="post">
  <input id="page_title" name="page[title]" type="text">
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Page">
</form>
```

I run two kinds of feature specs, those that are the same no matter what the language, and those that are I18N specific (for internationalization testing).

The problem is there is no clear way to click that submit button with capybara, unless I'm missing the obvious. I would expect simply `click('commit')` to do the trick.

- Using `click_button('Update Page')` works but is obviously language specific and can't be used with both the New and Edit templates even though they render the same form template.
- Adding an id to the submit button works, but I strongly dislike changing the code exclusively because the test requires it.
- Using a css or xml matcher both looks ugly (a user would never know/care about accessing an element that way) and it is overkill.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the end a macro was the answer I needed as apparently there is nothing native in capybara.

```
# spec/support/form_helpers.rb
module FormHelpers
  def submit_form
    find('input[name="commit"]').click
  end
end
```

This gets included in spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FormHelpers, :type => :feature
  ...etc...
```

I used `:type => :feature` so it gets included only in the integration tests.

In the integration tests you can use it like this:

```
scenario 'pages can be created' do
  visit new_page_path
  fill_in 'page_title', with: 'A Tale of Two Cities'
  submit_form # Clicks the commit button regardless of id or text

  expect(page).to have_content 'The page was created'
  ...etc..
end
```

Of course `submit_form` can also be used inside `within` blocks and with `:js => true`.

Comment: how did you import it in `rails_spec.rb`?

Comment: It depends on your configuration, but you could add `require 'spec/support/form_helpers.rb` to the top of the file if you used the path I suggested above.

Answer (score 11):

I usually do:

```
within 'form#edit_page_1' do
  find('input[name="page[title]"]').set "Some Value" 
  find('input[name="commit"]').click
end
```

Its tied to the html but to its semantic attributes, so I feel like its fine.
Actually I never use the magical finders.

Btw I dont understand your comment: `(a user would never know/care about accessing an element that way)`.

Integration specs are for you, it mimics a user for sure but its just a matter of giving proper instructions.

Comment: In general agree with you that tests are "for me". But they're also read by my designer and product manager, both of which shutter at anything that looks remotely like code. In that respect, I've been really happy and pretty amazed how close to plain English capybara can be (without cucumber). I've used .click as well but the css selector is something I wanted to avoid and thought there might be a magical finder. I'll probably use it though and make a macro for readability.

Comment: if you want super clean macro, use page objects and the great https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
find('input[name="commit"]').click
```

It helps